# Замена изображения с игры в формате текств

Tags: android

Всем привет.
Значит решил я заменить картинки одной игры на Android, а именно изображения скина с CS:GO.
На помощь пришел APK Editor,
вообщем суть моего обращения к вам:
В папке assets где должны быть изображение скинов, каждому скину выделили один файл с названием по типу 2f9582c91, если проще сказать зашифрован. (ниже будет скрин-шот)[image: скрин]

Вообщем в каждом из этих файлов находиться такой текст как:

"����������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������������butterflyknife_doppler(phase2)�C@CHB??�jܟ�FHv��c}Ҭ�8 E *   �R��?��L�=@���=@R����z�?���ף�����(ܿfff?�뿚��?H������?H����p�?��A�o�@�WC�/C��A�o�@����@HBCHB�B�?"�z@����G@�(\����?����ff�?��L�ףp?��u��Q8?�Q8>?�Q8>�Q�>ף>��>{�>�����(?�Q8�p=�?R���=�?�뿅��?ף���?����)\�?������?�㿅�?ף��#?��(�{�>��̽ף<)\��#���u=)\����=\�¾)\�>�Q8�\��>�p=�=�>p=�)?����?fff��?ff��ff�?ff��@ff�{@�(ܿ��@�ǿ��@�Q��"

текст не полный, но как я понял там находиться изображение скина в тексте,
так вот, хочу спросить можно ли заменить это изображение, если это не изображение, поправьте, мучаюсь уже месяц +-, буду рад любой помощи.